# How to avoid reading data from R environment within Rcpp function

Tags: r, optimization, rcpp

Even though `MyCppFunction(NumericVector x)` returns the desired output, I am not sure of a proper/efficient way to avoid reading the data on variable `myY` withou passing it as a function argument.

The reason I do not pass the data as an argument is that I will eventually pass the C++ function as an objective function to minimize and the minimization routine accepts a function of one argument only, namely `myX`. <s>Just as an example: in R, I would pass `myY` to `optim(...)` in the following way : `optim(par,fn=MyRFunction,y=myY)`.</s>

Any advice on how to properly access `myY` from within the C++ function is appreciated, here's a minimal example of what I am afraid is a really wrong way to do it:

**Update** : I've modified the code to better reflect the context as well as what has been proposed in the answers. Just in case, the focus of my question lies on this line : `NumericVector y = env["myY"];  // How to avoid this?`

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double MyCppFunction(NumericVector x) {

  Environment env = Environment::global_env();
  NumericVector y = env["myY"];  // How to avoid this?

  double res = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) res = res + (x(i) * y(i));

  return res;
}

double MyCppFunctionNoExport(NumericVector x) {

  Environment env = Environment::global_env();
  NumericVector y = env["myY"];  // How to avoid this?

  double res = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) res = res + (x(i) * y(i));

  return res;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double MyCppFunction2(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
  double res = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) res = res + (x(i) * y(i));

  return res;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double MyRoutine(NumericVector x, Function fn) {

  for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) fn(x);

  return 0;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double MyRoutineNoExport(NumericVector x) {

  for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) MyCppFunctionNoExport(x);

  return 0;
}

/*** R
MyRFunction <- function(x, y=myY) {
  res = 0
  for(i in 1:length(x)) res = res + (x[i]*y[i])
  return (res)
}

callMyCppFunction2 <- function(x) {
   MyCppFunction2(x, myY)
}

set.seed(123456)

myY = rnorm(1e3)
myX = rnorm(1e3)

all.equal(MyCppFunction(myX), MyRFunction(myX), callMyCppFunction2(myX))

require(rbenchmark)

benchmark(MyRoutine(myX, fn=MyCppFunction),
          MyRoutine(myX, fn=MyRFunction),
          MyRoutine(myX, fn=callMyCppFunction2),
          MyRoutineNoExport(myX), order="relative")[, 1:4]

*/
```

**Output**:

> ```
> $ Rscript -e 'Rcpp::sourceCpp("stack.cpp")'
> > MyRFunction <- function(x, y = myY) {
> +     res = 0
> +     for (i in 1:length(x)) res = res + (x[i] * y[i])
> +     return(res)
> + }
>
> > callMyCppFunction2 <- function(x) {
> +     MyCppFunction2(x, myY)
> + }
>
> > set.seed(123456)
>
> > myY = rnorm(1000)
>
> > myX = rnorm(1000)
>
> > all.equal(MyCppFunction(myX), MyRFunction(myX), callMyCppFunction2(myX))
> [1] TRUE
>
> > require(rbenchmark)
> Loading required package: rbenchmark
>
> > benchmark(MyRoutine(myX, fn = MyCppFunction), MyRoutine(myX, 
> +     fn = MyRFunction), MyRoutine(myX, fn = callMyCppFunction2), 
> +     MyRoutineNoEx .... [TRUNCATED] 
>                                      test replications elapsed relative
> 4                  MyRoutineNoExport(myX)          100   1.692    1.000
> 1      MyRoutine(myX, fn = MyCppFunction)          100   3.047    1.801
> 3 MyRoutine(myX, fn = callMyCppFunction2)          100   3.454    2.041
> 2        MyRoutine(myX, fn = MyRFunction)          100   8.277    4.892
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution.  Set global in C space:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

static NumericVector yglobal;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void set_Y(NumericVector y) {
  yglobal = y;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double MyCppFunction(NumericVector x) {
  double res = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) res = res + (x(i) * yglobal(i));
  return res;
}
```

R side:

```
set.seed(123456)

myY = rnorm(1000)
set_Y(myY);
myX = rnorm(1000)

MyCppFunction(myX)
```

(Note: the purpose of `static` is to limit the scope of the variable to your particular script)

Answer (score 3):

Use two parameters and wrap the C++ function in an R function.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double MyCppFunction(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
  return (sum(x) + sum(y));
}
```

R side:

```
callMyCFunc <- function(x) {
   MyCppFunction(x, myY)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've also tried that. The problem is that the function will be called from a C++ loop and hence wrapping it as an R function ends up being slower than using my original R version.

Comment: I've modified the code and included your answer. However this is on of the solutions I'm trying to avoid...

Answer (score 2):

`optim` does allow one to pass additional variables.  Here we minimize `f` over `x` and pass in the additional variable `a`.

```
f <- function(x, a) sum((x - a)^2)
optim(1:2, f, a = 1)
```

giving:

```
$par
[1] 1.0000030 0.9999351

$value
[1] 4.22133e-09

$counts
function gradient 
      63       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am aware of that. I probably shouldn't have mentioned `optim`. I mentioned it as an example of what I cannot do and what is forcing me to make the `Environment::global_env()` call inside of the C++ function. I will think of a more concrete example.

Comment: If you really are using a routine that does not accept additional fixed parameters you can curry your function like this:   `library(purrr); f2 <- partial(f, a = 1); optim(1:2, f2)`

Comment: I've modified the question in case you want to take a look. I'd prefer a base R\Rcpp solution though.